# How can I find integer values for which a given expression gives a perfect square?

Tags: quadratic-forms

Find the integer values for which $x^2+19x+92$ is a perfect square.

Also, How to proceed if you have to find values ( not necessarily integer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x^2+19x+92=(x+a)^2$ where $a$ is any real number

$\displaystyle\implies x=\frac{a^2-92}{19-2a}$

If you allow non-integer values, for any real value of $a, x^2+19x+92$ will be perfect square

If we restrict the solution to integers only,   $a$ has to be integer (why?)

Let integer $d$ divides  both $a^2-92,19-2a$

$\displaystyle\implies d$ divides $2(a^2-92)+a(19-2a)=19a-184$

$\displaystyle\implies d$ divides $19(19-2a)+2(19a-184)=7$

$\implies (a^2-92,19-2a)|7$

So, the necessary condition of $x$ being integer is the denominator $19-2a$ must divide $7$

$\displaystyle\implies 19-2a=\{\pm1,\pm7\}$

Check for all the four cases

Comment: +1 nice approach. Though technically, the phrasing of "let integer $d$ divides both ... " wouldn't be correct, since for example 2 divides 4 and 6 but 4 does not divide 6. You 'fixed' it at the end by saying that $19-2a = d$.

Comment: @CalvinLin, how have you come up with the example. To me, it should be : If $2$ divides $4,6;2$ will be divide $6A+4B$

Comment: Oh, what I meant was, you want it to be "$19-2a$ has to divide $a^2 - 92$". Simply checking for common factors is not good enough. You should explain at the start of the step what you are doing.

Comment: @CalvinLin, got your point, refactored the answer

Answer (score 4):

Complete the square:

$$\begin{align}
x^2 + 19x + 92 &= m^2\\
\iff (2x)^2 + 2\cdot 19\cdot (2x) + 368 &= (2m)^2\\
\iff (2x+19)^2 + 7 &= (2m)^2\\
\iff (2m)^2 - (2x+19)^2 &= 7.
\end{align}$$

Since $7$ is prime, that means $2m = \pm 4$ and $2x+19 = \pm 3$.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to bound the expression between two consecutive squares. We can show that when $ x > - 8$,

$$ (x+9)^2 < x^2 + 19x + 92 < (x+10)^2. $$

When $x < - 11$.

$$ (x+9)^2 > x^2 + 19x + 92 > (x+10)^2. $$

Hence, we only need to test $x = -11, -10, -9, -8 $.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at writing this as equal to $(x+9)^2 =x^2+18x+81$.  Put this equal to your expression, and you get $x+11=0$.  Similarly, other polynomials give similar results.

Comment: This approach would suggest that we need to look at all polynomials of the form $ (  x + n)^2$, since you have provided no restriction.