# How can I find values for which a given expression gives a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratics, quadratic-forms

There have been several posts on this topic on math.se, such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487363/how-can-i-find-integer-values-for-which-a-given-expression-gives-a-perfect-squar) one with the same title. However all the posts I found contained coefficients to $x^2$, that were perfect squares. I am looking for integer values for which $5x^2+2x+1$ is a perfect square.

EDIT: After looking at the first few solutions I have come to the conjecture that the only solutions is two consecutive fibonnaci multiples. i.e. $2=1\cdot2, 15=3\cdot5, 104=8\cdot13,  714 = 21\cdot34$

Comment: The following are the first few values of $x$ for which $5x^2 + 2x + 1$ is a perfect square. This is only to help anyone solve the problem. $x = 0,2,15,104,714$ and it is a square of $1,5 , 34, 233, 1597$ respectively

Comment: Multiply by $5$ and complete the square. We get the equation $(5x+1)^2-5y^2=-4$, for which we use standard Pell Theory. Note the appearance of the familiar Fibonacci numbers in the list given by Shailesh. This is not at all an accident!

Comment: @AndréNicolas  So, $F_{n}F_{n+1}$ are solutions for every odd n ?. I was trying to find what that product is and why it satisfies.

Comment: We are essentially solving $s^2-5t^2=-4$, with the side condition $s\equiv 1\pmod{5}$. So we end up  looking at odd powers of $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Except I think half the odd powers give us $s\equiv -1\pmod{5}$.

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048216__